# Converting nested loops to Java 8 streams

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8

I have following nested for loops which I need to convert to declarative code.

```
for (String variable : variables ){
      boolean validAttribute = false;
      if(variable.equals(SOME_CONSTANT)){
          validAttribute = true;
      }
      else {
         for(String attrName: attrNames){
            if(variableName.equals(attrName)){
                validAttribute = true;
                break;
            }
         }
      }
      if(!validAttribute){
          return false;
      }
 }
```

I am able to achieve it some how using the `flatMap`. But doesn't seem efficient as the earlier for loop use to break at the first non-matching entry. Is there any other simpler way?

(Also the code below seems difficult to understand)

```
List<String> inValidVariables = attrNames.stream().flatMap(attrName -> variableNames.stream()
                            .filter(variableName -> !variableName.equals(attrName) && !variableName.equals(SOME_CONSTANT)))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
 return inValidVariables.size() ==0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally i would solve this like that

```
    variables.stream().allMatch((item) -> item.equals(SOME_CONSTANT) 
                                || attrNames.contains(item));
```

I think streams should make your task easier not more complicated, that is reason why i didn't use it for inner loop as you can refactor this.

here is [link](http://ideone.com/dB57C8) to ideone where you can run both methods

Comment: I like your answer even more (I was thinking to complicated)

Comment: And I'm using the streams api not that long. But wouldnt a parallel stream make it (much?) faster?

Comment: @griFlo i don't know, i started looking at java8 yesterday:)

Comment: Thanks, meets my expectations.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should match your requirement:

```
variables.stream().noneMatch(variable-> !variable.equals(CONSTANT)&&attrNames.stream().noneMatch(attrName -> variable.equals(attrName)));
```

returns `true` if the each variable is equals the CONSTANT or one of the attrNames.

else it returns `false` (if ther is any variable which doesnt match the CONSTANT or any attrName)

Comment: Can't you do `variable -> stuff` instead of `variable -> {return stuff;}`?